# associate name with ip for ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ip, ip-address, host

Let's say I just have an ip address for a server and I don't have a domain with it (it's just a database server, so it doesn't need a domain). I don't want to have to remember the ip address every time, so is there a way I could still use the syntax like `ssh username@database` or something?

Comment: This is mistake primarily in terminology. Replace the word "domain" with a correct word "name" and  you will immediately see it. "I say the server doesn't need a name, so I would really like to refer to it by name" is a self-contradiction. Maybe your real questions should be "What is a domain? How to add a new name to a domain?"

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you only want the name for ssh and ssh only, you can add a name to your ssh config in ~/.ssh/config

As an example, your config file could look like this:

```
Host database
    HostName <real IP address or hostname here>
    User username
```

Then you can type `ssh database` on the command line and ssh will automatically do `ssh username@ip.address` for you.

Comment: If in the HostName field I can put only the hostname or the IP, then how do I specify the hostname-IP association?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri you would put the hostname in the Host field, like "database" in the example, and (just) the IP address in the HostName field.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying to figure out how to do this from Termux and I don't have sudo on my android phone so I couldn't edit the /etc/hosts file. But this worked. AWESOME.

Answer (score 13):

Add an entry for it to `/etc/hosts` on the system you're ssh'ing from.

The syntax is

```
1.1.1.1 hostname
```

This works on Linux and Mac.  For Windows, the file is `c:\windows\system\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: This will definitely work, but be advised that the hosts file is sometimes overwritten by network managers.  Also you have to have root privileges so this is only an option if you have root.

Comment: But is this method secure and safe to practice?

Answer (score 2):

clients have 2 or 3 ways to associate a name with a IP address.

1) DNS, but that implies a hostname and a domain.

2) host file, you can add any name in the clients host file and then it
will be used. Add the line '192.168.1.1 database' in /etc/hosts
to associate the name database with the address 192.168.1.1. 
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29 for more specific details and OS specific locations.

3) NIS, Solaris computers can use NIS to share hostnames for multiple clients.

Comment: Or LDAP. Or mDNS. Or any NSS-enabled mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to add the `database` name-IP mapping to your `/etc/hosts` file. The hosts file can be easily edited. You will find some entries there.

This name can be used for any connection not just SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/index3.html), it's free, in five minutes you can add a A record that points to your IP.

For example: create database1.dyndns.org as an A record pointing your ip
You can access from everywhere using:

> ssh username@database1.dyndns.org